# How to delete an element from the list of tuples matching only on first value of the tuple in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter

How can I delete an element from the list of tuples matching only on first value of the tuple.

```
delete (2, _ ) [(2, True), (3, False)]
```

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: Hint: check module `Data.List`. there is a function which does this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case the signature looks like:

```
delete1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
```

We can use recursion to look for matches in the 2-tuple, the function can thus looks like:

```
delete1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
delete1 y = go
    where go [] = …  -- (1)
          go (x:xs)
              | y == x = …  -- (2)
              | otherwise = …  -- (3)
```

where filling in the `…`s is left as an exercise. In the first case (`(1)`) the list is exhausted, so we can return an empty list.

For the second case (`(2)`), the have found a match, so in that case we recurse on the tail of the list.

In the last case, the item `x` does *not* match with `y`, so in that case we yield the item and recurse.

We however do not have to implement the recursion ourselves, we can [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) the list, and thus implement a function like:

```
delete1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
delete1 y = filter func
    where func = …
```

Here the `…` part needs to return `True` in case we want to keep the item, and return `False` in case we want to filter out that value.